# C get all open file descriptors

Tags: c, io, file-descriptor

I want to implement behavior in my C program so that if a SIGINT happens, I close all open file descriptors. Is there a simple way to get a list of them?

Comment: after you `exit();` or `return` from main, the kernel should close those file descriptors for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use brute force: `for (i = 0; i < fd_max; ++i) close (i);`. Quick and pretty portable.

Comment: Obviously much easier, yes!-) But the race might still be an issue.

Comment: You might want to use `getrlimit(RLMIIT_NOFILE, &rlim)` to find the maximum `fd_max`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to close the file descriptors for `stdin`. `stdout` and `stderr` (0, 1, 2)?

Comment: @alk The OP states "close all open file descriptors", that includes those for the stdio streams.

Answer (score 5):

Keep track of all of your open file descriptors and close them individually.

In the general case, a library you're using might have an open file, and closing it will cause that library to misbehave.

In fact, the same problem could exist in your own code, because if you close file descriptors indiscriminately but another part of your program still remembers the file descriptor and tries to use it, it will get an unexpected error or (if other files have been opened since) **operate on the wrong file**. It is much better for the component responsible for opening a file to also be responsible for closing it.

Answer (score 5):

You could read out the content of `/proc/<pid>/fd.`, if available.

But be aware of the potiential race, that might occur if your application closes some or opens new ones in between your read out `/proc/<pid>/fd` and you are going to close what you read.

So conculding I want to recommend Kevin Reid's approach to this.

Comment: Why do you assume, `/proc` is available? It's about the most unportable nightmare in existence.

Comment: You are right. I modifed my comment to be suitable for certain systems only. @Jens

Comment: If concerned about portability, you could read `/dev/fd/`. This is more portable than `/proc/self/fd`.

Comment: In the /proc/<pid>/fd directory were listings of the file descriptors and their corresponding files in my case, e.g. "70 -> /file/location/file.blah". This was really handy in my opinion because then I could pinpoint in my program where these files were being opened and not closed.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for POSIX systems:

All opened fd's are the lowest value possible.
Make a wrapper function upon `open(2)`.
Your new function open (and return) the requested fd and pass his value to a function called `define_if_is_the_higtest_fd_and_store_it()`.
You should have a `int hightest_fd_saved` accessible only for a singleton function (there is only 1 'descriptor table') named `save_fd()` (initial value is 3 (cuz `stderr` is 2)).
Configure `SIGINT` to your signal function. Inside, you do a loop from [3, `return_fd()`].

I think that's it...