# C program in Linux to read a file descriptor passed as a terminal argument

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, unistd.h

I've been looking into different discussions how to get the open file descriptors for a current process on Linux from a c program, but could not find the following example:

```
./sample 4</some_file 5<some_other_file
```

Is there any way to get those file descriptors in a `sample.c` program in this case. I found out that those redirections are not treated as command line arguments. Hope someone can help.

Ofcourse fds 4 and 5 are given just as example, I would like the program to find out which fds were open on execution.

Comment: You can just use file descriptors 4 and 5 in the code. Are you asking how the program can know which ones you redirected?

Comment: I have edited the question :) sorry.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101690/c-get-all-open-file-descriptors)?

Comment: @Kevin I have been looking at this example, but it somehow does not seem elegant... I thought the clearest way would be to get the fds as arguments in this way if it is possible ofcourse.

Comment: Then you can certainly pass the fds as arguments as well: `./sample 4 4<file1 5 5<file2`. Redirection happens before `./sample` starts, so it doesn't know what happened unless you tell it.

Answer (score 2):

Given `sample` is started by

```
./sample 4</some_file 5<some_other_file
```

this will provide file descriptors that can be used to access those files:

```
int fd_for_some_file = 4;
int fd_for_some_other_file = 5;
```

If you don't want to assume file descriptors are fixed values, don't assign the files to hardcoded descriptor values when you start your process.

Edit:

> I would like the program to find out which fds were open on execution.

In general, I don't think you can.

If, however, your code to identify pre-opened file descriptors runs before any invocation of `open`, you may be able to just run through values greater than 2 to see what they are using OS-specific means.  On Linux:

```
for ( int fd = 3; fd < fd_max; fd++ )
{
    sprintf( linkname, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd );
    int rc = readlink( linkname, linkvalue, sizeof( linkvalue ) ); 
    if ( rc == 0 )
    {
         // found a file opened by calling process
    }
}
```

Yes, that's inherently racy for multithreaded programs. If you're using GCC, you can put the code in a function with `__attribute__(( constructor ))` and it will run before `main()` is called.  But even that could identify files opened by other such functions as being passed by the parent process.

Comment: I did not mean fds 4 and 5 were "static". I want to find out which fds were open after the execution. Sorry for an unclear question.